# pause a running batch file if user presses a key. Opposite of normal pause function?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, user-input, pause

I have sections of a batch file that pause and wait until a user presses a key.

But what if i want the ability to pause the batch file while it is running on my own free will?

The batch file creates a user input variable:

```
SET /P userInput= enter something here
```

Later in the process i may want to update that user variable. but it will be at unexpected times.

Can i interrupt the batch file process, then update the variable, with out stopping or closing the entire batch process?

Basically, the idea is that the batch file is creating unique file names and sometimes i need to update its naming structure. being able to stop the program and just change that variable would be great.

so program starts:

```
Set /p userInput : something entered

does stuff..
does stuff..

//User hits  a key and program pauses
//prompt for userInput variable again:

Set /p userInput : something new

// then continue as normal

does stuff..
does stuff..
```

etc..

Maybe its possible to CALL a subroutine via keyboard press while the batch is running as another option?

Thanks for reading!!

Comment: Only thing I can think of is to have your `does stuff...` sequence check the contents of a text file or a registry value on each iteration, and modify that value when you want the processing changed.  Or maybe have your `does stuff...` stuff check the process list for `choice.exe` and stop if `choice` isn't running.  When `choice` isn't running, the user has started input.  When user input is finished, restart the `does stuff...` stuff with the new params (rather than resuming).  I've found about a dozen different ways to fail, but haven't found a way to succeed yet.

Answer (score 1):

The Batch file below do exactly what you requested:

```
@echo off
setlocal
if "%1" neq "" goto %1

SET /P userInput= enter something here

echo Start batch
del flagFile.txt 2> NUL
"%~F0" Input | "%~F0" Process
echo End batch
goto :EOF


:Input
rem Wait for any key
pause > NUL
rem Get the new value
cd . > flagFile.txt
set /P "userInput=Enter new value: " > CON
echo %userInput%
goto Input


:Process
echo Current value: %userInput%
ping localhost -n 2 > NUL
if not exist flagFile.txt goto Process
set /P "userInput="
del flagFile.txt
goto Process
```

Note that you had *not* stated how the process ends, so I will add such part as soon as you describe this point...